# Handling lots of variable declarations

Tags: c++, variables, scope

I am implementing a class and I have a function that does things using lots of variables that need to be declared and initialised.

I'd like the variable declarations not to clutter the function and do something like:

```
doFunction(){
  declare();

  //Do things with variables declared in declare()
}
void declare(){
  //declare lots of variables here
}
```

This does not work as the variables are scoped to declare() and aren't seen by doFunction(). What's a sensible way to handle this problem?

Comment: There could be different ways of handling this depending on what exactly your problem is. Could you give a bit more context? Solutions range from restructuring your code, to making a support class containing all the variables, to making a macro.

Comment: Don't have huge functions. Don't pollute the scope. Use containers. Factor things in a logical fashion.

Comment: If your function requires so many variables that it's become a problem, I'd argue that there is likely a problem with the design of the function, that it should in fact be split up into multiple functions or otherwise redesigned. I would arue this _might_ be an example of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem where you've realised your function is too big/complex and decided the solution is to hide the variable declarations and asked about that rather than the problem itsself. I might be wrong though :)

Answer (score 2):

Since each of the variables that you declare must be assigned a value, you should combine declaration with initialization. In other words, instead of

```
int x;
double y;
std::string z;
x = 1;
y = 2.0;
z = "3";
```

do this:

```
int x = 1;
double y = 2.0;
std::string z("3");
```

This is pretty much as far as you can push this approach with locals: declaring variables is an essential part of the function body, you cannot (and arguably, should not) move it to a remote location.

You can also move the member function into a nested private class, move the local variables into the class, and do calculations there:

```
class specialCalc {
    int x;
    double y;
    std::string z;
    specialCalc() : x(1), y(2.0), z("3") {}
public:
    int calculate() {
        ...
    }
};

void doFunction() {
     specialCalc calc;
     cout << calc.calculate() << endl;
}
```

PS: I am deliberately not mentioning preprocessor-based solutions because they would negatively impact readability.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really advocating this, but:

```
struct Declare
{
    int x;
    float y;
    char z;
    vars() :x(1),y(3.14),z('z') {}
};

void doFunction()
{
    Declare vars;
    // use vars.x, vars.y and vars.z as your variables
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the method you got? you place a lot of related data into a simple struct. I'll +1 for now until you can give me a good reason why you would not recommend it.

Comment: @ahenderson: There's nothing wrong with the method, for solving the "problem" that the OP describes.  What I mean is that the OP's problem is not a real problem, or at least, he is going about solving it in the wrong way.  I would agree with the comments under the question.  If the function becomes so large that the declaration of variables actually makes the function more difficult to comprehend, refactoring is needed.  I didn't get the sense from the question that the data are related, other than the fact that they are used in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of choices:

1) Get over it.  If you need lots of variables, you'll need to suffer the fact they need to be declared somewhere.

2) Put them into a class or in a structure as a member variable so you can declare them in the .h file and they'll be invisible in the .C/.cpp file.

3) Aggregate them into an array, and declare only the array and initialize them in  a `for()` loop or something.  This really only works if they're all a similar type and you don't do silly things like "index 4" is my "counter object for this", and "index 5" is my "thing I'm going to print to the screen" as then you loose the name associated with the variable itself, which is rather helpful when reading the code later (of course).

4) put them in a define statement somewhere else:

```
#define MYVARS int a; char b[1024]; ...

void funstuff() {
    MYVARS
}
```

5) Modify an IDE so that it can hide/collapse the variable declarations when you're viewing the code.

Note that of all of these choices, number 1 is still probably the right answer :-)